# How to get rid of 'incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'val')], ..'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, python-typing, keyword-argument

I'm trying to forward and/or store `Callable`s while providing as much type hinting as possible. Currently I'm struggling with a `mypy` error that seems simple, but I somehow cannot solve it. Imagine this little snippet containing a collection of `Callable`s:

```
from collections.abc import Callable, MutableSequence

functions: MutableSequence[Callable[[int], None]] = []

def foo(val: int) -> None:
    print(val)

functions.append(foo)
```

While somewhat senseless, it works and `mypy --strict` gives me zero issues.

Now I want to make `foo` accept only named parameters:

```
def foo(*, val: int) -> None:
```

and `mypy` gives me

```
./foo.py:11: error: Argument 1 to "append" of "MutableSequence" has incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'val')], None]"; expected "Callable[[int], None]"  [arg-type]
```

.. which sounds plausible, but is there a way to get around this? `NamedArg` can't be imported via `typing` or `typing_extensions`, but only via `mypy_extensions`, which feels strange to have it as a dependency.
But even when I accept it, it gives me a class, rather than some `Generic`.

How can I solve this without losing type hinting for the named arguments?

Btw, in a real-life-project I'm forwarding kw-args, so allowing the list in the snippet above to only accept a kw-arg with one (generic) argument name like `MutableSequence[Callable[[NamedArg(int, 'val')], None]]` would be fine.

Comment: `Callable[[int], None]` **must** allow calling as `func(1)`, which is not the case with kwonly argument. Define a `Protocol` with `__call__` method that fits your needs, like `class MyCallback(Protocol): def __call__(self, *, val: int) -> None: ...`

Answer (score 0):

What you need if the `Callable[...]` syntax doesn't suffice to define your signature is a [Callback Protocol](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols).

Applied to your example it'd look like this:

```py
from collections.abc import MutableSequence
from typing import Protocol

class FooCallable(Protocol):

    def __call__(self, *, val: int) -> None:
        ...

functions: MutableSequence[FooCallable] = []

def foo(*, val: int) -> None:
    print(val)

functions.append(foo)
```